# Possible reasons why "location.reload(false)" reloads page from server?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I am using

```
location.reload(false);
```

And for unknown (to me) reason page is relaoded from server (page is php generated, css, javascripts and imagefiles are refreshed, i can see this information in chrome developer tools for example.

What are possible reasons that can cause reloading page from server?

EDIT1:
I sent header to use cache and to set expire date 5 years from today, is there anything else that i am missing?

EDIT2: I have 3 pages with same resources, and if i simply click link from one of these to other or if i click link leading to current page, resources are loaded from cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [the `forceget` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) is set to false, the browser isn't *forced* to reload the page from the server, but it is still free to do so.

Check the caching headers of the page you're generating. If you send the correct headers, the browser should fetch it from its cache.